# Error al momento de deseleccionar los datos de una tabla

Tags: java

Buenos dias,

Este es mi codigo:

```
public void seleccionarTodos(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
   if(isIsSelectedAll()==true){        

        this.selectedFuentes=fuente;
        setIsSelectedAll(false);

    }else{
            this.selectedFuentes.clear();
            setIsSelectedAll(false);
      }
}
```

> tengo una tabla con un checkbox general que al momento de presionarlo
>   me seleccionara todos los datos que contenga la tabla (la tabla
>   contiene un paginado)
>
> entonces cuando realizo la primera busqueda, me muestra los datos (los
>   datos aparecen seleccionado por defecto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> cuando le doy click al checkbox general funciona bien, pero si dejo
>   deseleccionado los datos y realizo otra busqueda, mostrara los datos
>   seleccionado por defecto pero al momento de dar click al checkbox para
>   deseleccionarlos, ocurre algo muy raro(se deseleccionan los datos y
>   nuevamente se seleccionan) y no se que hacer.

Este es el codigo de la tabla:

```
    <p:dataTable  id="datos" var="f"  rowKey="#{f.num}"
              resizableColumns="true" value="#{busquedaBean1.fuente}"
             selection="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}" style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top: 0%;"  
             rows="11" paginator="true"  paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" >

    <!-- CONTENIDO DE LA TABLA -->
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" global="true"  listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"   />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" global="true"  listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"   />

    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" global="true" update="datos"  listener="#{busquedaBean1.seleccionarTodos}"   />

    <p:column headerText="Nombre" style="width:80%;" sortBy="#{f.nombre}">
        <h:outputText value="#{f.nombre}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Fecha" style="width:108%;" sortBy="#{f.fecha}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{f.fecha}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Bloqueo" width="65" sortBy="#{f.bloqueo}">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{f.bloqueo}" rendered="#{empty f.fechaBloqueo}" style="padding: 0 20%;"/>                                       
        <p:commandButton value="#{f.bloqueo}" rendered="#{ not empty f.fechaBloqueo}" id="detBloqueo" update=":form:carDetail" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="Mostrar detalles" style="background: transparent;  color:#4297d7;border: 0px;" styleClass="detalles">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{f}" target="#{busquedaBean1.autor}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>


    <p:column width="16" >
        <h:commandLink title="Descargar" target="_blank"  actionListener="#{descargarFormaBean.descargar(f.forma,f.nombre)}">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" style="text-align:center;"></span>
        </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Directorio" width="190" sortBy="#{f.directorio}">
        <p:commandButton value="#{f.dir}"  id="detDirectorio" update=":form:dirDetail" oncomplete="PF('dirDialog').show()" title="Mostrar detalles" style="background: transparent;  color:black;border: 0px;" styleClass="detalles">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{f}" target="#{busquedaBean1.autor}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>

    <p:column  id="SelectFuentes"   style="width:16%;text-align:center" selectionMode="multiple" exportable="true"   >

    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Por favor comparte el código relevante de la vista (imagino que es código Facelets para JSF y/o PrimeFaces)

Comment: te refieres al del checkbox?

Comment: osea el codigo de la tabla?, si es primefaces

Comment: Así es, el código de la tabla, checkboxes, etc. Todo el código necesario que nos permita replicar el problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza listo amigo ese es el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solución y lo que pasaba era que el valor no se resetea así que lo resetie cada ves que iba a realizar una busqueda de esta manera, lo unico que hice fue agregar esto:
`isSelectedAll = false;` y listo problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas el `rowUnselectCheckbox` y tambien puedes incluir el  `rowSelectCheckbox`

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"   listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"/>
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"/>
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"   listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"/>
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{busquedaBean1.selectedFuentes}"/>
```

Comment: no amigo eso no tiene nada que ver, el problema persiste